# Cascading divs with triangles pointing downwards

Tags: html, css

What would be the easiest way to create the following (see image) with triangles at the bottom of the div.

[image: Cascading Triangles]

I have tried using the css after method but get overlapping triangles. I am thinking the easiest way maybe to just create background images of the triangle on each div.

```
    .triangle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.triangle::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0px;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    bottom: -2em;
    left: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1em solid black;
    border-color: transparent transparent white white;

    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);

    box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a perfect job for `clip-path`:

```css
.container {
 padding:20px;
 background:#dce2cc;
}
.box {
  height:200px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(70% - 30px) 0, 70% 15%, calc(70% + 30px) 0, 100% 0, 100% 85%, calc(70% + 30px) 85%, 70% 100%, calc(70% - 30px) 85%, 0 85%);
  background-color:red;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
.box:first-child {
   clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 85%, calc(70% + 30px) 85%, 70% 100%, calc(70% - 30px) 85%, 0 85%);
}
.box:last-child {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(70% - 30px) 0, 70% 15%, calc(70% + 30px) 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%,0 100%);
}
.box:not(:first-child) {
   margin-top:-10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=0)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=1069)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=1072)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/500/500?image=1052)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using css `:after` and `:before` see below working snippet

```css
body{
 background:rgb(220, 226, 204);
}
.arrow {
 position: relative;
 background: #fff;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.arrow:after, .arrow:before {
    top: 88%;
    left: 80%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 12px 0px rgb(220, 226, 204));
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 12px 0px rgb(220, 226, 204));
}

.arrow:after {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-width: 35px;
    margin-left: -35px;
}
.arrow:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-top-color: #fff;
 border-width: 38px;
 margin-left: -38px;
}
.arrow.no-arrow:after,.arrow.no-arrow:before{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
   
<div class="arrow">
  content goes here
</div>
<div class="arrow">
  content goes here
</div>
<div class="arrow no-arrow">
  content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: What you offering seems not inline with question owner expectation. Container item also have to be shrink from top right area.

Comment: @VikasJadhav Still not inline, from what I can tell; the background image of the div isn't a continuous background for the arrow.